# How to cut in middle of lumber with miter saw

Tags: cutting, miter-saw

How can I use a mitre saw to cut in the middle of astock (as seen in the picture)? If this would be hard to do with a mitre saw, what tool would be best?

My assumption is that mitre saws go all the way through the lumber, and you can't put a stopper.

[image]

Comment: Which other tools do you own? This is simple job for hand tools.

Comment: This feels very much like a spam seed question as an excuse to post the video linked in the OP's answer. However, from the part I watched, there didn't seem to be a specific brand involved, (I didn't really listen to hear if a brand was mentioned), so I won't VtC, but this just feels... _icky_...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not show any investigation and may be a spam post.

Comment: No, is not a spam seed question. It was a legitimate question on how to do lap join cuts with a miter saw. I'm learning wood working. If we are closing questions based on them "feeling icky", or because they might be a "spam post", then that's messed up. We shouldn't close questions based on feelings or assumptions, but rather on facts. I did some investigation and couldn't see find the proper way to accomplish this, until I found out the name of this type of joint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this effectively/efficiently with a (non-sliding) mitre saw.

Other suitable tools for this job are a handsaw and chisels, a router, and/or you might be able to clear some of the material with a drill and a forstner bit.

You may also be able to make some use of a handheld circular saw as in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wnmCGicpOfY

...but honestly that looks like it takes about the same amount of time as it would to just go at it with a handsaw and some chisels, if you've had a bit of practice, depending on the type of wood.

You could also probably make some use of a jigsaw or an oscillating multi-tool (such as a Fein multimaster)... really there are dozens of ways to make a basic notch such as this. Many YouTubers etc. seem to show "shortcut" ways of doing things which often involve a table saw or sliding mitre saw, but those tools really aren't necessary for most jobs. It's worth taking the time to learn to do things "the old fashioned way" as these skills will be useful to you at some point - there are many jobs such as modifying timbers already in place during home renovations where you can't take the piece out and put it on a table saw or mitre saw, for example.

There are a number of good videos on how to notch wood with various tools (including basic hand tools only) here:

https://www.luxuryhomestuff.com/notching-wood/

Answer (score -4):

The answer is to use a depth control device, as [seen in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1crx-Sela7A).

Comment: It's important to note that the video referenced uses a sliding miter saw. A conventional miter saw, without the sliding feature will not offer this utility.

Comment: And that device seems loose, floppy, and very lightly constructed at best, with no depth measurements. I only watched a minute or so and stopped it. Doesn't seem like a reliable, credible source of _safe_ and proper tool use.